# Android and iOS Label line count Angular/Nativescript

Tags: android, ios, label, angular2-nativescript, mobile-development

I'm relatively new to Angular/Native/Mobile dev. I need to figure out the **line count on a Label** element, after it has been rendered on the screen. I have been trying to find a solution online for a while now, with no result - maybe I'm searching for the wrong stuff? I really expected that would have already been implemented as part of Label/UILabel, I don't know, I'm lost. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After giving the documentation another look, I figured it out. Nativescript's Label is based on [Android's TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) , there is, of course, an implementation for line count - to get it, just use getLineCount() . Can't believe I missed that before. Thought I'd post the answer anyway, for anyone else, who's great at overlooking obvious things, like me.